# Get HTML content out of apps script application

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I've been struggling with this a while. My script runs from within a spreadsheet to update a site with its data formatted as HTML.

Within the script I'm using `app.add(app.createHTML(values[i][j]))` within a loop over the data range. I'm also appending various panels within this loop.

At the end I then find the page I want to update in the site and call `page.setHtmlContent(app)` which obviously doesn't work - what do I need to do here instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object `app` is a UiApp instance, not an html content. One should consider it more as a command that tells the Google server to generate an html page using GWT toolkit so obviously (as you said) the code you tried can't work.

If you try to get the content of the shown page using something like

```
  var htmlContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKf------Z1BBusUdHBmbWI-eqNjM/exec').getContentText();
```

you will see that it looks like anything but an understandable html code , plus you will meet issues with authorizations, warning messages and/or 'loading' messages...

As far as I know there is not way to capture the html content from a webapp in a form that would be compatible with the site method `page.setHtml`, at least not using Google Apps Script methods.

maybe some hack somewhere but not that I know...

Comment: Thanks, that's a good explanation. I tried the fetch and I got some standard Google login page as my content so I'm in the process of converting all my app code to HtmlService